# Rank of block matrix structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given matrix $B$ of size $n\times n$ with rank $r>1$.

Denote $S_r$ as $n\times n$ permutation matrix that shifts each row one step down while elevating last row to first.

Denote $S_c$ as $n\times n$ permutation matrix that shifts each column one step right while elevating last column to first.

Form $n^2\times n^2$ block matrix $W$ with $i,j$th block of matrix being $B_{ij}=S_r^{j-1}BS_c^{i-1}$. (Note $j-1$ is for row rotations).

Total number of matrices $B_{ij}$ is $n^2$.

$W$ satisfies row sum = column sum.

Is $\mathsf{rank}(W)\geq rn$?

Comment: Is $B_{ij}$ the element at row $i$ and column $j$, or the other way around?

Comment: ah i see there is a confusion

Comment: Your edit didn't help. Does $B_{ij}$ go in the $i$-th block row of $W$ or the $j$-th block row of $W$? The usual convention is that the first index indicates the row.

Comment: @VictorLiu $i$th.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $B$ be the matrix of all $1$'s. Then $B_{ij}$ is always the matrix of all $1$'s, and so is $W$. In this case, $r=1$, but $\operatorname{rank}(W) = 1$.

Comment: Is example obvious for $r>1$?